# Adding "Used by" inside the github project with gradle and java

Tags: java, gradle, github

I have a problem to understand how to add the "used by" inside my project java with Gradle.

- My question is, is possible to add the used by with Gradle inside the java project?
- Is possible using the "used by" inside a for the project? (stupid question)

Information on the project

The repository of the project is loaded to sonatype.

Sorry the question very stupid, but I don't understand how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finded a solution and I will try to describe it.

Github has not supported the "Dependency graph" with gradle but supported the maven, so Github when fint the "pom.xml" inside the root directory, create the Dependency graph, so we can enable the "used by" for the project.

Now for resolve the problem I need to create the pom file with gradle, with this code

I have created the file gradle.proprieties with this proprieties

```
GROUP_ID = your group id
ARCTIFACT_ID = your arctifact id
VERSION = your version
```

I have added this task inside the build.gradle, it used the maven plugin

```
   apply plugin: 'maven'

    task createPom {
        pom {
            project {
                groupId GROUP_ID
                artifactId ARCTIFACT_ID
                version VERSION

                inceptionYear '2019'
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'MIT'
                        url 'https://github.com/vincenzopalazzo/material-ui-swing/blob/masternow/LICENSE'
                        distribution 'repo'
                    }
                }
            }
        }.writeTo("pom.xml")
    }
```

For enable the "used by" inside the project I have used this [guide](https://help.github.com/en/articles/listing-the-packages-that-a-repository-depends-on)